# how to execute a function with two parameter using one string as a paramter?

Tags: javascript, string

Sorry if my question title looks different to what my question. I couldn't find the right words but here is my question:

Lets say there is a function like this:

```
function sum (a, b){
      return a+b;
}
```

Instead of using sum like this with two number

```
const t = sum (2, 3);
```

I want to use like this, if possible:

```
var s = "2, 3";
const t = sum (s);
```

Thank you.

Comment: you want a function that takes a string with a format of two numbers separated by a comma and returns the sum of those two numbers?  Is the return value a string or a number?  Why do you use const in your examples?

Comment: @Hogan `const` should be preferable to `var` and `let` when creating variables, when possible - makes the code easier to read and debug, usually. (the real question might be why `var` is there if `const` is permitted :P )

Comment: @Hogan first question is yes. second question is a number. Third question: it can be "var" ot anything that can hold an integer...

Comment: @CertainPerformance -- sure - but as the code stands it is clear `s` is const and we don't know what `t` would be used for.  This suggests the poster also did not know which to use.   I guess I was really asking -- why use const for `t` and not for `s`

Comment: Mamun below has the right answer, but IMO this is the wrong question: you should really not do this. If your input is a string, you should parse it *before* passing it into your `sum()` func instead of re-writing the function to accept such an odd input.

Comment: I have a feeling like there's going to be a much better alternative for you than what you are considering.  I just can't tell because you haven't told us your motivation for doing what you are doing.  Are you aware of things like the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object? or the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function? or [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html).   I'd really like to know the deeper reason you want to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `split()` the string so that you can get the number from the generated array using *index*.

**Please Note:** You have to convert the string representation of number to number before performing arithmetic operation. Otherwise string concatenation will happen.

```js
function sum (str){
  str = str.split(',')
  var a = Number(str[0]), b = Number(str[1]);
  return a+b;
}

var s = "2, 3";
const t = sum (s);
console.log(t);
```

If you do not want to change the function then get the number from the string and pass those to the function:

```js
function sum (a, b){
  return a+b;
}

var s = "2, 3";
s = s.split(',');
var x = Number(s[0]), y = Number(s[1]);
const t = sum (x, y);
console.log(t);
```

Comment: what if i cant alter the function sum?

Comment: @NahPrime -- then give it a different name, like `SomeOtherSum`

Comment: @NahPrime, I have added another solution in the answer.....please check.

Comment: @NahPrime, if you can't alter that function, then create another function, because, this will be not efficient, `split`ting the `s` variable everytime you use `sum` function, checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `split()` like this:

```js
const t = (s) => Number(s.split(',')[0]) + Number(s.split(',')[1]);

var s = '2, 3';
console.log(t(s));
```

Here, `split()` function takes a parameter of `string`, and `return`s a `list` containing the segments splitted by the given parameter.

`Number` function takes `string` and `return`s the respective value in `int`, because if we take `string` values like this:

```
'2' + '3'
```

then, the output would be `'23'` (*String concatenation*) which we don't need

As you've mentioned if you can't alter the function `sum`, then you can use this approach (*by making another new function*):

```js
// sum function definition without alteration.
function sum (a, b){
      return a+b;
}

// New function
const t = (s) => sum(Number(s.split(',')[0]), Number(s.split(',')[1]));

var s = '2, 3';
console.log(t(s));
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using braces for an arrow func that only contains a return statement? I'm of the opinion that if you need braces, you should use regular `function() {}` syntax anyway but this is a whole new level

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum (a, b){
      return a+b;
}

var s = "2, 3";
var arrOfNums = s.split(",").map(d => +d);
const t = sum(...arrOfNums);

console.log(t); //5
```

If you don't want to alter your method you can see above alternative approach. Here:
1. First, I split your string using ',' which give Array('1', '3') and then used [array's map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array with the result of calling a provided arrow (d => +d) function to every element of the array, `d => +d` runs for each element and converts string to integer using javascript's [Unary Plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

2. Secondly, I use [Array spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which expands array elements in place of function argument, you can also use `arrOfNums[0]` and `arrOfNums[1]` in place of this spread syntax.

Comment: you really should explain what you are doing here, while readers who know js will be impressed with your ability to use the language, the poster will have no idea what you did and why it is better (or worse) than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try  this**

```js
function sum (a, b){
      return a+b;
}

var string = "2, 3";
var arr = string.split(",").map(Number);
const t = sum(...arr);

console.log(t);
```

Comment: you really should explain what you are doing here, while readers who know js will be impressed with your ability to use the language, the poster will have no idea what you did and why it is better (or worse) than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could also be to use `eval`:

```js
var s = '2, 3';
function sum(a, b){
      return a+b;
}
console.log(eval(`sum(${s})`)); // <-- similar to sum(s);
```

Admittedly, this isn't the best solution. If `s` is provided from a third party source (ie via user input), do not use this solution, as malicious code can be injected into the value of `s` and ran.

Also, `eval` is an expensive function to run. Thus, instead, you could use the alternative, `window.Function`:

```js
const s = '2, 3';
const sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
const functionCall = `sum(${s})`; // <-- similar to sum(s);
const res = Function('return ' + functionCall)();
console.log(res);
```

This, provides a method of evaluating which is much faster than `evel` however, this has its vulnerabilities.